# Can't understand why regex doesn't work with start/end markers of the string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-3.0

Here is my test regex with options IgnoreCase and Singleline :

> `^\s*((?<test1>[-]?\d{0,10}.\d{3})(?<test2>\d)?(?<test3>\d)?){1,}$`

and input data:

```
      24426990.568   128364695.70706     -1288.460
```

If I omit **^** (match start of line) and **$** (match end of line)

> `\s*((?<test1>[-]?\d{0,10}.\d{3})(?<test2>\d)?(?<test3>\d)?){1,}`

then everything works perfectly.

Why it doesn't work with string start/end markers (^/$)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you change that * to .*?

Comment: This regex correctly doesn't match the string, as there is only one check for a space at the first position, but there are spaces inside the string.

Comment: @Sebastian Proske: Well, it is not spaces in common sense rather it is missing digits. Exact format should be something like  128364695.70706358364695.12346 with no spaces.

Comment: @Sharov the reason is in my answer; it has to do with the mode and the meaning of ^ and $ in the different modes

Comment: @BugFinder: No, it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to allow for spaces between your tests ..  at the moment you have no spaces allowed for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The start and end is literally the start and end of the input string when in single line mode. 
It only means the start of the line and the end of the line in multiline mode.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended)

Please note that this means the **entire** input string.

So if you use:

```
      24426990.568   128364695.70706     -1288.460
```

as your input string, then the beginning is the first white space and the end of the string will be the `0`

As your pattern matches exactly one instance of what you are looking for the regex will fail when used with ^ and $. This is because it is looking for one instance of that pattern in the input string, but there are three.
You have two options:

1. Remove the ^ and $
2. Change the pattern to match at least one time

Comment: Ok, I artificially add some spaces at the end and still no match.

Comment: @Sharov the spaces are not the problem, it's the meaning of ^ and $ in singleline mode as I say above; have you understood my answer? if not, let me know what doesn't make sense and I will edit

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't get it. Ok, ^ take one space from the beginning and $ get last 0. As a test I append three spaces and it should work. But it isn't.

Comment: @Sharov the ^ matches the beginning of the string and $ matches the end of the string; this means that regex expects what's between ^ and $ to match **exactly**; in your case you have three instances of that pattern between ^ and $, so it won't match

Comment: and that's why it works when you remove ^ and $, because it just looks for that pattern in the **entire** string ignoring the requirement to match the pattern once from the beginning to the end of the string

Comment: According to your comments and my understanding following string should work (without ") "       24426990.568   128364695.70706     -1288.46000 ". The entire stiing now between anchors is "      24426990.568   128364695.70706     -1288.4600" which should have 3 match. But it hasn't. And also when I omit $ it has only one first match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118458/discussion-between-the-bearded-llama-and-sharov).